# How can I import an svg image in new Figma

Tags: svg, import

I am not finding the import option in new figma design and I am facing difficulties.

I tried to find import image from main menu option but place image option is missing now

so its creating difficulties for me to work on figma

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the Dev mode: <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

or click the `</>` button in the top-right corner:

[image: switch]